Mbed-OS6にNucleoF446REを接続していますが、Keil studio のDebugボタンがグレイのままでデバッグできません。
Mbed OS上のKeil studioでプロジェクトを正常にビルドでき、NucleoF446REに書き込みもできます。しかし、Debugボタンがグレイのままです。cannot debug for selected target and project combination.と表示されます。ターゲットボードとプロジェクトの組み合わせに問題があるようですが、どなたか解決策をお知らせください。

自己解決できました。
これまでは、ボードを接続して、オープンしたドライブに表示されたリンクからMbed OSに接続し、さらに表示されているボタンでKeil Studioを開いていました。これだと接続状態が不安定で、切断、接続を繰り返すような状況でした。
以下の方法で解決できました。

STLinkをバージョンアップする。
Chromeで https://www.keil.arm.com に行って、Arm Keil | Development Tools for IoT, ML and Embeded。
Arm Keil MDK v6 が開いたら、ボードをPCに接続する。ドライブがオープンするが、無視。
右下のDetect Connected Boadボタンをクリック。
接続要求一覧から「STM32STLink-ペア設定済み」を選んで、接続ボタン。
右下にDetected hardware:としてBoadとDeviceが表示されるので確認。
右上のKeil Studio Cloudクリック。
Keil Studioが開いて、Build、Run、Debugボタンが全てイネーブルになっている!!!

上記の手順でKeil Studioに接続すると、安定した接続が維持されるようになりました。
